# unreachable code al usar if en Java

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo java en la uni y debo terminar este codigo, pero tengo un problema con el `if` y no he podido saber cual es, disculpen si es algo muy bobo, estoy aprendiendo recien, gracias de antemano

```
public double calcularPremioEquipo( String pCodigo )
{
    double premio = 0;

    if (equipo1.darCodigo().equals(pCodigo));
    {
        premio=equipo1.calcularPremioBase();
        if (equipo1 == darPrimerLugar());
        {
            premio = premio + BONIFICACION_PRIMER_LUGAR;
            return (double) premio;
        }

        else if(equipo1 == darUltimoLugar());
        {
            premio= premio - DEDUCCION_ULTIMO_LUGAR;
            return (double) premio;
        }

        if (premio < 0);
        {
            premio= 0.0;
            return premio;
        }

    }

    if (equipo2.darCodigo().equals(pCodigo));
    {
        premio=equipo2.calcularPremioBase();
        if(equipo2 == darPrimerLugar());
        {
            premio = premio + BONIFICACION_PRIMER_LUGAR;
            return (double) premio;
        }
        else if (equipo2 == darUltimoLugar());
        {
            premio= premio - DEDUCCION_ULTIMO_LUGAR;
            return (double) premio;
        }
        if (premio < 0);
        {
            premio= 0.0;
        }
    }

    if (equipo3.darCodigo().equals(pCodigo));
    {
        premio=equipo3.calcularPremioBase();
        if(equipo3 == darPrimerLugar());
        {
            premio = premio + BONIFICACION_PRIMER_LUGAR;
            return (double) premio;
        }
        else if (equipo3 == darUltimoLugar());
        {
            premio= premio - DEDUCCION_ULTIMO_LUGAR;
            return (double) premio;
        }
        if (premio < 0);
        {
            premio= 0.0;
        }
    }

    if(equipo4.darCodigo().equals(pCodigo));
    {
        premio=equipo4.calcularPremioBase();
        if (equipo4 == darPrimerLugar());
        {
            premio = premio + BONIFICACION_PRIMER_LUGAR;
            return (double) premio;
        }
        else if (equipo4 == darUltimoLugar());
        {
            premio= premio - DEDUCCION_ULTIMO_LUGAR;
            return (double) premio;
        }
        if(premio < 0);
        {
            premio= 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

[image: captura de error]

Comment: y que error te da al compilar?

Comment: Mira http://prntscr.com /eeaag2 quita el space, te agradecería si me ayudas

Comment: En vez de tener 4 variables `equipo1`  `equipo2`  `equipo3`  `equipo4` y repetir el mismo codigo casi clavado 4 veces, no seria mas facil usar una lista?

Answer (score 3):

El error está en que no todas las partes del código devuelven un valor. para solucionar esto puedes añadir un `return premio;` al final de la función antes del último corchete.

Edito: no había visto el otro error, tienes que quitar el `;` al final de los `If`. El código quedaría más o menos así:

```
public double calcularPremioEquipo( String pCodigo ) 
{
  double premio = 0; 
  if (equipo1.darCodigo().equals(pCodigo))
  {
    premio=equipo1.calcularPremioBase();
    if (equipo1 == darPrimerLugar())
    {
        premio = premio + BONIFICACION_PRIMER_LUGAR;
        return (double) premio;
    }

    else if(equipo1 == darUltimoLugar())
    {
        premio= premio - DEDUCCION_ULTIMO_LUGAR;
        return (double) premio;
    }

    if (premio < 0);
    {
        premio= 0.0;
        return premio;
    }

}

if (equipo2.darCodigo().equals(pCodigo))
{
    premio=equipo2.calcularPremioBase();
    if(equipo2 == darPrimerLugar())
    {
        premio = premio + BONIFICACION_PRIMER_LUGAR;
        return (double) premio;
    }
    else if (equipo2 == darUltimoLugar())
    {
        premio= premio - DEDUCCION_ULTIMO_LUGAR;
        return (double) premio;
    }
    if (premio < 0)
    {
        premio= 0.0;
    }
}

if (equipo3.darCodigo().equals(pCodigo))
{
    premio=equipo3.calcularPremioBase();
    if(equipo3 == darPrimerLugar())
    {
        premio = premio + BONIFICACION_PRIMER_LUGAR;
        return (double) premio;
    }
    else if (equipo3 == darUltimoLugar())
    {
        premio= premio - DEDUCCION_ULTIMO_LUGAR;
        return (double) premio;
    }
    if (premio < 0)
    {
        premio= 0.0;
    }
}

if(equipo4.darCodigo().equals(pCodigo))
{
    premio=equipo4.calcularPremioBase();
    if (equipo4 == darPrimerLugar())
    {
        premio = premio + BONIFICACION_PRIMER_LUGAR;
        return (double) premio;
    }
    else if (equipo4 == darUltimoLugar())
    {
        premio= premio - DEDUCCION_ULTIMO_LUGAR;
        return (double) premio;
    }
    if(premio < 0)
    {
        premio= 0.0;
    }
}
return premio;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Miguel, ya veo que cometía un grave error. Lo tendré mas encuenta

Comment: @DiegoPatiño tiene mucho codigo igual pero no voy a entrar en eso, pero por ejemplo esta linea  `if (premio < 0);
        {
            premio= 0.0;
            return premio;
        }` la usa en muchas partes pero sin el return `if(premio < 0)
    {
        premio= 0.0;
    }` en el caso de usar el codigo de miguel el incorpora un return premio casi al final con lo que soluciona eso, pero quizas lo pueda tener en cuenta. Por otro lado de acuerdo con miguel usted usa el punto y coma en lugares erroneos...

Comment: ... *Java utiliza el punto y coma para indicar el final de una sentencia* y *Las estructuras de control determinan la secuencia de ejecución de las sentencias de un programa.* no llevan punto y coma. Saludos

Comment: @DiegoPatiño Bienvenido si tiene tiempo creo que puede mirar este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que vea como funiona el sitio mas o menos, sobre los votos ect.Saludos